# Get number in string with a regexp

Tags: java, regex, numbers, space

I'm trying to get numbers from a String. Numbers only separated by space.
This code works a lot of case except I've got two numbers separated with only one space.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^|\\s)[0-9]+(\\s|$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
while (matcher.find()) {
    numericResquest.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group().trim()));
}
```

For example:

- **OK**: 11 rre 12
- **OK**: 11  12 *(two spaces between the numbers)*
- **Can't find 11** test 12 11 rre *(only one space between the numbers)*

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just match the digit in your regex with lookarounds:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\s)[0-9]+(?=\\s+|$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
while (matcher.find()) {
    numericResquest.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()));
}
```

Comment: This will work but does not test the correctness of the input. So it also accepts strings like 'abc34cde'.

Comment: Because I don't want match words which contains number like test98

Comment: Yes the solution was (?=X) , via zero-width positive lookahead and
(?<=X) , via zero-width positive lookbehind. I didn't know it thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] numbers = value.split(" ");
for(String number : numbers) {
    numericRequest.add(Integer.parseInt(number));
}
```

If you get a `NumberFormatException`, the input was not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, not counting cases at the beginning or end of the string, your pattern requires a space both *before* and *after* the number.  So if your string is `"11 12"`, the first match will find `"11 "`, with a space at the end.  The matcher's index will point after the pattern, i.e. to `"12"`.  But since the pattern also requires a space at the beginning, the next attempt to match won't work, because there's no space at the beginning of `"12"`.

One way to solve this while using the same approach: Use `matcher.lookingAt` instead of `matcher.find`; `lookingAt` will match only if there's a pattern starting at the current index.  Then you can fix your pattern so that there doesn't have to be a space at the beginning.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*[0-9]+(\\s|$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
while (matcher.lookingAt()) {
    numericResquest.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group().trim()));
}
```

This allows, but doesn't require, any number of spaces at the current index before the number occurs.

(Note: I haven't tested this.)

Answer (score 0):

### Regex

```
(^|(?<=\s))(\d+)(?=\s|$)
```

**Iterate over all matches and capturing groups in a string**

```
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(^|(?<=\\s))(\\d+)(?=\\s|$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            // matched text: regexMatcher.group(i)
            // match start: regexMatcher.start(i)
            // match end: regexMatcher.end(i)
        }
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```